# RANX returning 1's only when grouping applied

Tags: dax, powerpivot, rank

In Power Pivot, this DAX formula ranks all values in the `Sales` column:

```
=RANKX(ALL(Table2),[Sales])
```

The resulting table:

```
Group | Sales | Calculated Column
    A | 2     | 4
    A | 3     | 3
    B | 4     | 2
    B | 5     | 1
```

When I try to create ranks within groups, this formula returns all 1's in the calculated column.

```
=RANKX(ALL(Table2[Group]),[Sales])
```

Like this...

```
Group | Sales | Calculated Column
    A | 2     | 1
    A | 3     | 1
    B | 4     | 1
    B | 5     | 1
```

Is there something wrong with the formula?

Answer (score 0):

```
=RANKX(FILTER(ALL('Table2'), 'Table2'[Group] = EARLIER('Table2'[Group])), [Sales])
```